# bootstrap4-datetimepicker time-picker positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please assist with the below issue:

I am using https://github.com/technovistalimited/bootstrap4-datetimepicker and trying to display the clock on the right hand side underneath `focusable message span` but its one component and strungling to align it please see example image [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOm0Z.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="section schedule bg-white">
                    <h3 class="breakword" role="heading" aria-level="2">Select time</h3>
                    <div id="datetimepicker" class="schedule-picker"></div>
                    <div class="schedule-picker">
                        <div>
                            <div class="schedule-time-picker"><span class="focusable message" tabindex="0" aria-label="Select a service and date to see available times.">Select a service and date to see available times.</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Schedule */

.schedule-picker {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 392px;
    margin: 0 40px;
    text-align: left;
}

.schedule-time-picker span.message {
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    display: block;
    cursor: auto;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: normal;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    margin: 1px;
}

@media (max-width: 1020px) {
    .schedule-picker {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .schedule-time-picker {
        max-height: inherit;
        width: 330px;
        margin: 32px auto 16px;
    }
}
```

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like some of the styling is missing. I would double check that you have the bootstrap 4 CSS as well as the bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css linked up correctly. I would also check that you dont have any custom styling that may be overwriting the date picker css.

Comment: I have double checked everything is linked up correctly all I am trying to achieve is moving the time picker only under `<span class="focusable message" ...` if its possible